# get href link from webpage and download

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to bind a code that get href link(download link) from webpage and start download in vb.net

Here is the full code of which link should be captured..

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://dl3.com/store/download/details?id=test.apk" target="blank" class="download btn btn-success btn-md" title="Download Test File"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Download File (48M) </a>
```

Please help me to bind the code ..

Comment: The `href ` value is probably wrong  because I clicked it and doesn' t download anything. Another thing is the `target` value should be `_blank` not `blank`.

Comment: yeah, i changed the download link but it will gonna be same as above ..

Comment: If the link works this markup should work too

Comment: no the target value is     blank not     _blank

Comment: `var client = new WebClient();
var text = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/page.html");` ??